can you do variable substitution inside tfvars files
Is there a way to set a variable at the top of a tfvars file and have it substitute further down in the tfvars file...  so something like this.
#########################
# CHANGE THESE VARIABLES#
#########################
name = "abc123"

...

alb_r53_default_zone_domain_name = "${name}.example.pvt."

I have looked around but have not found any example of someone doing this.
any help would be appreciated.

use locals for that :)

No, you cannot do that. If you need something like that, you could use the local variables, something like:
locals {
  alb_r53_default_zone_domain_name = "${var.name}.example.pvt."
}

and you would then use the local variable with local.alb_r53_default_zone_domain_name instead of var.alb_r53_default_zone_domain_name. Alternatively, you could just use the same string interpolation without adding another variable.
